# How to wait until a specific file arrives in a folder before NiFi's ListFile processor lists the entire contents of the floder

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to move several hundred files from a Windows source folder to a destination folder together in one operation. The files are named sequentially (e.g. part-0001.csv, part-002.csv).  It is not known what the final file in the sequence will be called.  The files will arrive in the source folder over a number of weeks and it is not ascertainable when the final one will arrive.  The users want to use a trigger file (i.e. the arrival of a spefic named file in the folder e.g. trigger.txt) to cause flow to start. My first two thoughts were using a first ListFile processor as an input to a second, or the input to an ExecuteProcess processor that would call a script to start the second one, however, neither of these processors accept an input, so I am a bit stumped as to how I might achieve this, or indeed if it is possible with NiFi. Has anyone encountered this use case, and if so how did you resolve it?

Comment: Did not get `neither of these processors accept an input...` can you please elaborate on what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for the question Vikramsinh. To clarify, what I mean is that you can't route the output of a ListFile processor to another ListFile processor or to an ExecuteProcess processor.